Horror movie set in hospital
The movie was made (I believe) between 2005 and 2012, though i think closer to the former.
Basically I remember a girl being locked in a hospital (I believe it was a psych hospital) and I remember she and her friends were there. They were all separated. 
The girl went to find her friends when something seemed off about the hospital. She found her boyfriend (assuming because she kissed him) but he was all cut up and alive. 
This is a bit graphical: his entire body was stretched out by the veins. His whole body was stretched out (torso, legs, arms. Not in small sections) and you could see his body hanging from the ceiling. 
He told her to get out of there while she could. Find the others and go. I don't remember if she killed him or if he died from the experiment. All I can remember is she was the only one who got out after killing the nurse. 
I believe she ended up there due to a car crash, but don't hold my word on that.

Any idea as to what the country of origin was?  Was it dubbed in another language?  Major studio release?  Did the special effects look real, or were they poorly done?  Anything like this that you can add to it will help.

Autopsy (2008)


Five friends go to New Orleans Mardi Gras. On their way home, they get into a car accident and realize they have hit a man. Before anyone
    can call for help, an ambulance arrives. They are taken to a strange
    hospital where their injuries can be examined.

The plot centers on Mercy Hospital where inhumane experiments are
  being done on the living patients by an insane staff. The
  "experiments" are brutal, often killing the victim. In one set piece,
  the internal organs of a patient are hung like a garland over the
  autopsy table. The experiments are designed to save the head doctor's
  wife, who has a terminal disease.


